program in Linux using strace
i very new to Linux , i was asked to tell what a program does after running it using strace
i would like to get some hint or help how even to read, are those linux command or specific  language '(
this is the program after running using strace
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x80002 (flags O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55abccdbf000
brk(0x55abccde0000)                     = 0x55abccde0000
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
write(3, "Error. The program should receiv"..., 62Error. The program should receive a single argument. Exiting.
) = 62
write(3, ": Success\n", 10: Success
)             = 10
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?

or im i even doing it right, or it says smtg i did wrong here?

Those are Linux system calls. You can look them all up in the man pages to find out what they do.

You can't tell everything a program is doing from strace. It only shows the parts that need to call into the kernel, not the calculations done in user code or libraries.

Why were you asked to do this if you don't understand it? If this is a class assignment, didn't they teach the background information?
